# Can I copy & paste an entire article from Medium if it's written by me?

Tags: copyright

If I use the blogging platform Medium, to which extent can I (not) reuse the content I have published there on a personal blog website? My naive view on that matter is:

- I am still the owner of the text and can republish it anywhere, same goes for own or public domain images
- I can use links with text and image previews on my own blog, linking to Medium-posts
- I cannot embed Medium posts in an Iframe on my own site
- I cannot copy comments from medium which belong to their rightful owner, even if I participate in the discussion under the article

Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much everything you need to know about the ownership and licensing of your material on Medium is in the Medium TOS you contractually agreed to when you signed up with the service. Basically, you granted Medium a license to use the work, but you did not agree to an exclusive license nor turn over copyright to them.

Part of that [Terms of Service – Medium Policy](https://medium.com/policy/medium-terms-of-service-9db0094a1e0f) reads:

> Content rights & responsibilities
>
> You own the rights to the content you create and post on Medium.
>
> By posting content to Medium, you give us a nonexclusive license to
>   publish it on Medium Services, including anything reasonably related
>   to publishing it (like storing, displaying, reformatting, and
>   distributing it). In consideration for Medium granting you access to
>   and use of the Services, you agree that Medium may enable advertising
>   on the Services, including in connection with the display of your
>   content or other information. We may also use your content to promote
>   Medium, including its products and content. We will never sell your
>   content to third parties without your explicit permission.
>
> You’re responsible for the content you post. This means you assume all
>   risks related to it, including someone else’s reliance on its
>   accuracy, or claims relating to intellectual property or other legal
>   rights.
>
> You’re welcome to post content on Medium that you’ve published
>   elsewhere, as long as you have the rights you need to do so. By
>   posting content to Medium, you represent that doing so doesn’t
>   conflict with any other agreement you’ve made.
>
> By posting content you didn’t create to Medium, you are representing
>   that you have the right to do so. For example, you are posting a work
>   that’s in the public domain, used under license (including a free
>   license, such as Creative Commons), or a fair use.
>
> We can remove any content you post for any reason.
>
> You can delete any of your posts, or your account, anytime. Processing
>   the deletion may take a little time, but we’ll do it as quickly as
>   possible. We may keep backup copies of your deleted post or account on
>   our servers for up to 14 days after you delete it.

Pertaining to presenting Medium content in an iFrame on another site, this is reasonably close to not allowing that:

> You may not do, or try to do, the following: ... (2) access or search
>   the Services by any means other than the currently available,
>   published interfaces (e.g., APIs) that we provide;...

You can use [Embed Code Generator | Embedly](https://embed.ly/code) to embed an iFrame of a Medium page on another site. But contacting Medium via the email at the bottom of the TOS would tell you for sure if it is OK.

Comments on your pieces on Medium do belong to the owner.

And

> You own the rights to the content you create and post on Medium.

appears to cover the idea of copying your material from Medium to your own site. If in doubt, ask them.